# UI Local notification in Single App mode

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

UILocalNotification is not coming when i have supervise my iPad in single app mode. Same code is working fine when device is in normal mode when app is in background/killed or any other state. 
But after Supervise device in single app mode with same app Notifications is not coming.
In my case app will never gone in background but may be device in sleep mode.

Comment: Please share your code. Most likely you are not handling the notification presentation when the app is in the foreground. Also what OS version are you building against? iOS 9/10?

Comment: Same in my case, I am Showing one alert in 'didReceiveLocalNotification' and if i am stop single app mode then it is working fine. 
But after enable "Sinlge app mode" nothing is working. 
And i am using iOS 9 and 10 both.